# How do I set which level is the "event" in my outcome variable using tidymodels?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I am using [tidymodels](/questions/tagged/tidymodels) for machine learning and I want to predict a binary response/outcome. How do I specify which level of the outcome is the "event" or positive case?

Does this happen in the recipe, or somewhere else?

```r
##split the data
anxiety_split <- initial_split(anxiety_df, strata = anxiety)


anxiety_train <- training(anxiety_split)
anxiety_test <- testing(anxiety_split)


set.seed(1222) 
anxiety_cv <- vfold_cv(anxiety_train, strata = anxiety)

anxiety_rec <- recipe(anxiety ~ ., data = anxiety_train, positive = 'pos') %>%
  step_corr(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal(), -all_outcomes()) %>%
  step_zv(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, could you share a sample of your data? Just type `dput(head(anxiety_df))` in the console and paste the output in your question. That help us to help you

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to set which level of your outcome variable is the "event" until it is time to evaluate your model. You can do this using the `event_level` argument of most [yardstick](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/dev/) functions. For example, check out how to do this for `yardstick::roc_curve()`:

```r
library(yardstick)
#> For binary classification, the first factor level is assumed to be the event.
#> Use the argument `event_level = "second"` to alter this as needed.
library(tidyverse)

data(two_class_example)


## looks good!
two_class_example %>%
  roc_curve(truth, Class1, event_level = "first") %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

```r
## YIKES!! we got this backwards
two_class_example %>%
  roc_curve(truth, Class1, event_level = "second") %>%
  autoplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Notice the message on startup for yardstick; the first factor level is assumed to be the event. This is similar to how base R acts. You only need to worry about `event_level` if your "event" is not the first factor level.

Comment: Is it possible to set event_level earlier? I think it's a quality inherent in the data collected, before any metrics. For example, `predict(type="prob")` could output just the probabilities for the event level.

Comment: If you want to set that earlier, then yes, you do need to do it in your data itself, by explicitly setting the factor levels so what you want to be first is the first factor level. This is similar to how base R (like `lm()`) works.